# Coding pattern for calling a rest base wcf service from IOS

Tags: .net, ios, wcf, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to find out if there are any good patterns or coding standard for calling a WCF REST based api from objective c ios platform.  I have quite a few REST based WCF service methods needs that needs to be consumed from my IOS application.

Please suggest based on you coding experience with the above code requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code being used by the Facebook iOS SDK. It calls into the Graph API which is rest (not necessarily WCF). It's open source so you can take a look at what they're doing. The code is on github: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk